# Database not being updated with 'Edit user form'

Tags: php, mysql

I have an administrator page that allows admins to edit details of the users who have just registered. Everyone's 'access levels' are defaulted to 4 and it is up to the admin to change their access level to '2' for a tutor or '3' for a student.

**adminpage.php**

```
    <div class="container">
                    <h3> New Members </h3>

                    <?php

                    $query = "Select * FROM users WHERE accessLevel = '4'";

                    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
                    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                            $userID = $row['userID'];
                            $firstName = $row['firstName'];
                            $lastName = $row['lastName'];
                            $emailAddress = $row['emailAddress'];
                            $accessLevel = $row['accessLevel']; 

                            echo
                            "<div class = 'row'>
                            <div class='col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3'>
                            <div class='box'> 
                            <h5> User ID: $userID </h5>
                            <h5> User Name: $firstName $lastName </h5>
                            <p> Email: $emailAddress </p>
                            <p> Access Level: $accessLevel</p>
                            <a href = 'editUser.php?getUser=$userID' name='Edit Details' class = 'button'>Edit Details</a>
                            </div>
                            </div>



                            </div>";
                        }
                    }
```

**editUser.php**

```
    <?php
    include ('connection.php');
    $getID = $_GET['getUser'];
    $query = "Select * From users where userID ='$getID'";
    $return = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    ?>


 <?php
                include ('connection.php');
                $userQuery = "Select * FROM users WHERE userID = '$getID'";
                $return = (mysqli_query($conn, $userQuery));

                if (mysqli_num_rows($return) > 0) {
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($return)) {

                        $userID = $row['userID'];
                        $firstName = $row['firstName'];
                        $lastName = $row['lastName'];
                        $emailAddress = $row['emailAddress'];
                        $password = $row['password'];
                        $accessLevel = $row['accessLevel'];
                    }

                    echo
                    "<h5> Edit Profile for $firstName $lastName </h5>;

                    <form class ='form' method ='POST' name ='Update' action= 'updatedProfile.php?getid=$getID'>
                    <fieldset>
                    <legend>Update Profile Details</legend>
                    <div class = 'input-group fluid'>
                    <label for = 'userID'>UserID</label>
                    <input type = 'number' value='$userID' id ='userID' placeholder = 'UserID'>
                    </div>
                    <div class = 'input-group fluid'>
                    <label for = 'firstName'>First Name</label>
                    <input type = 'text' value='$firstName' id = 'firstName' placeholder = 'FirstName'>
                    </div>
                    <div class = 'input-group fluid'>
                    <label for = 'lastName'>Last Name</label>
                    <input type = 'text' value = '$lastName' id='lastName' placeholder = 'Last Name'>
                    </div>
                    <div class = 'input-group fluid'>
                    <label for = 'emailAddress'>Email</label>
                    <input type = 'email' value='$emailAddress' id ='emailAddress' placeholder = 'emailAddress'>
                    </div>
                    <div class = 'input-group fluid'>
                    <label for = 'emailAddress'>Password</label>
                    <input type = 'password' value='$password' id ='password' placeholder = 'Password'>
                    </div>
                    <div class = 'input-group fluid'>
                    <label for = 'emailAddress'>Access Level</label>
                    <input type = 'number' value='$accessLevel' id ='accessLevel' placeholder = 'Access Level'>
                    </div>
                    <button>Update Details</button>

                    </fieldset>
                    </form>         
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>";
                }
                ?>

                <?php
                include("connection.php");


                if (isset($_POST['userID'])) {
                    $userID = $_POST['userID'];
                } else {
                    $error = true;
                    echo "big error";
                }
                if (isset($_POST['emailAddress'])) {
                    $emailAddress = $_POST['emailAddress'];
                } else {
                    $error = true;
                }
                if (isset($_POST['firstName'])) {
                    $firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
                } else {
                    $error = true;
                }
                if (isset($_POST['lastName'])) {
                    $lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
                } else {
                    $error = true;
                }

                if (isset($_POST['accessLevel'])) {
                    $accessLevel = $_POST['accessLevel'];
                } else {
                    $error = true;
                }

                if (isset($_POST['password'])) {
                    $password = $_POST['password'];
                } else {
                    $error = true;
                }

                if (!$error) {
                    //$update = "UPDATE `rdonaghy08`.`users` SET userID='$userID', `firstName` = '$firstName', `lastName` = '$lastName', `password` = '$password', `accessLevel` = '$accessLevel' WHERE `users`.`userID` = '$getID'";
                    $update = "UPDATE users SET userID='$userID', firstName = '$firstName', lastName = '$lastName', password = '$password', accessLevel = '$accessLevel' WHERE userID = '$getID'";
                    $return = mysqli_query($conn, $update) or die(mysqli_errno($conn));
                }
```

**And finally, updatedProfile.php**

```
<?php
include 'connection.php';
$getid = $_GET['getid'];

if (isset($_POST['userID'])) {
    $userID = $_POST['userID'];
} else {
    $error = true;
}
if (isset($_POST['emailAddress'])) {
    $emailAddress = $_POST['emailAddress'];
} else {
    $error = true;
}
if (isset($_POST['firstName'])) {
    $firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
} else {
    $error = true;
}
if (isset($_POST['lastName'])) {
    $lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
} else {
    $error = true;
}

if (isset($_POST['accessLevel'])) {
    $accessLevel = $_POST['accessLevel'];
} else {
    $error = true;
}

if (isset($_POST['password'])) {
    $password = $_POST['password'];
} else {
    $error = true;
}


if (!$error) {
    $update = "UPDATE users SET userID='$userID', 
    emailAddress='$emailAddress',firstName='$firstName', lastName='$lastName'accessLevel ='$accesslevel',password='$password' WHERE userID = '$getid'";
    $return = mysqli_query($conn, $update) or die(mysqli_errno($conn));
} else {
    "something wrong";
}



$returnQuery = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userID='$getid'";
$return = mysqli_query($conn, $returnQuery);




if (mysqli_num_rows($return) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($return)) {
        $userEmail = $row['emailAddress'];
        $userID = $row['userID'];
    }
}


$content = "

            Please use the following link to login in with your 
                        new details: 
            http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@xxxxxxx.co.uk

                        Please make a note of your new User name, 
                        you will need this to log in to CaterVLE= $userID
            ";


$send = $userEmail;
$subject = "Log in Details";
$headers = "Content-type-type: text/html";


mail($send, $subject, $content, $headers);
?>
```

I know that is a lot of code to look at, I am seriously not looking anyone to do this for me, I just want to know if I am missing something simple or if I can be pointed in the right direction. The email gets sent OK, its just that the database never gets updated, specifically, the access level never gets updated, say from default 4 to 3.

Anyone able to help? Many Thanks!

Comment: `lastName='$lastName'accessLevel ='$accesslevel'` - missing a `, ` in between there. Throws an mysql error that you could ask for

Comment: why are you changing the userID in the update? its the value your using to select the row to update, so this makes no sense, and  $userID vs $getID

Comment: @smith - I should remove the SET userID = $userID?

Comment: do you want to change it?

Comment: No! I mean it doesn't need to be changed.